# Web Intelligence Not Showing Table

Tags: business-objects

When I run a query in Web Intelligence, I do not get any table as a result. 
Although during the report creation, when I click on regenerate, I get the set of data.
Problem is - how do I get a table as a result?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out, that our server has some problems, which are causing this behavior.